# Diagnosis of a CSS import statement error within a Bare React Native TypeScript project using React Native CSS Modules

Tags: css, react-native, import, eslint, prettier

So, I've been trying to get CSS (and to a perferable extent, SASS) setup and working within a Bare React Native TypeScript environment ([as TS has now got first-class support](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/01/03/typescript-first)).

I was hitting issue after issue but after following a fresh project initialisation and Kristerkari's GitHub instructions, I managed to get at least CSS styling up and running in a testbed environment. The test app bundles and launches succesfully, and one can see the app session update in real-time after saving changes (as one would come to expect).

However, **and this is the issue related to this thread**, an error appears on the import statement of the styles.css file within the test.tsx file, even though everything builds and bundles correctly:

```
Cannot find module './styles.css' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

As I mentioned, I first initialised a fresh Bare React Native TypeScript project by entering the following command using the React Native CLI:

```
npx react-native@latest init TestProject
```

I then followed Kristerkari's GitHub instructions on [setting up CSS modules for React Native (with CSS support)](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-css-modules/blob/master/docs/setup-css.md), while using npm equivalents to yarn.

While doing so I created a `src` folder within the project's root directory and created the following `styles.css` and `test.tsx` files inside this src folder:

```
// styles.css

.container {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.text {
  font-size: 16;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```
// test.tsx

import * as React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles.css';

const TestApp = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>
        This text should be center aligned to a red screen.
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default TestApp;
```

[Here is the resulting project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttWZw.png) in VSCode.

After all this, as I've mentioned, the app successfully built and bundled itself after launching it with the following npx command:

```
npx react-native start
```

[And here's evidence of the working real-time, bundled build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ans23.png) using an emulated Pixel 6 Pro device that was setup through Android Studio.

I'm honestly at a loss of why this error is appearing. I thought it may be something to with my lint and formatting solutions, [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) and [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) respectively, producing false positives. But alas, I disable both extensions and the error persists.

I know the import location is correct (`./styles.css`), as the styling defined in that .css file is being applied to the launched app in real-time, which wouldn't be the case if the import location wasn't correct.

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯` Could someone help diagnose this importing error, please?

I'd preferably like to get CSS properly working without any errors and with peace of mind before I move onto modifying the project's configuration to use SASS and ultimately moving on from there.

Any help would be much appreciated

**EDIT:** I've just tried modifying this project configuration to use SASS (out of curiosity), again by following Kristerkari's GitHub instructions (this time on the [SASS equivalent step-by-step](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-css-modules/blob/master/docs/setup-sass.md)), and essentially the same import error persists with another fully working real-time, bundled build:

```
Cannot find module './styles.scss' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```